# Conteúdo do select box muito grande

Tags: php, jquery, html, angularjs

Tenho um selectbox `<select>` HTML que tem um conteudo muito grande, são mais de 1000 registros que devem ser carregados, só que em questões de performance acredito que está ficando ruim.

Gostaria de alguma solução em javascript, jquery ou angular, que resolva meu problema de performance na hora de carregar os dados nesse selectbox.

Atualmente carrego meu selectbox assim:

```
<select id="id_empresa" class="form-control">                                   
    <option value="0">Todas</option>
    <?php foreach( $empresas as $empresa ): ?>
        <option value="<?=$empresa[ "id_empresa" ];?>"><?=$empresa[ "nome" ];?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>    
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resposta genérica: Se você tiver uma quantidade grande de registros, realmente o elemento select (ou similar) pode não ser uma solução adequada. Experimente algo que permita ao usuário realizar algum tipo de filtragem, populando o select via AJAX, de preferência limitando o máximo de registros que pode ser retornado.

Dê uma olhada nessa lista: [13 jQuery SelectBox/Drop-down Plugins](https://www.sitepoint.com/13-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins/);  dê preferência àqueles que tenham suporte a AJAX, para melhor limitar a quantidade de registros que precisarão ser carregados.

Comment: Só para complementar: No select box você pode usar a técnica de scroll infinito, trazendo de x em x dados ao chegar no final do select box.